# Spring Boot error "Request method 'POST' not supported" with Ajax function

Tags: java, ajax, spring-boot, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a page with url "http://localhost:8080/clientes/cadastrar" and I have a button in this page, when pressed the button opens a modal to insert some information(name,email,etc). The problem is that when I click the "Save button" in this modal, with an onclick function to call the Ajax function, I get the following error:

```
2021-03-11 16:30:31.973  WARN 1200 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]
```

Here is the AJAX function:

```
<script th:src="js/AddEmailCliente.js" th:fragment="js"></script>
    <script th:inline="javascript" th:fragment="inlinescript">
function salvarEmail() {
        
        var cliente = /* [[cliente]] */ 0;
        var nome = Document.getElementById('nome').value;
        var email = Document.getElementById('email').value;
        var envio_cobranca = Document.getElementById('envio_cobranca').checked ? true : false;
        
        
        $.ajax({
            url : "/emails/salvar",
            type : 'POST',
            contentType : 'application/json',
            data : JSON.stringify({
                idcliente : 'cliente.idcliente',
                nome : nome,
                email : email,
                envio_cobranca : envio_cobranca
            }),
            success : function(data) {
                session = data.session;
            }
        });
         
         
     } 
    
    </script>
```

Here is the controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/emails")
public class EmailController {

    @Autowired
    EmailService service;
    
    @Autowired
    ClienteService clienteService;
    
    
    @PostMapping("/salvar")
    public String salvar(BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes attr, @RequestParam Long idcliente, @RequestParam String nome, 
            @RequestParam String email, @RequestParam boolean envio_cobranca) {
            Email emails = new Email();
            Cliente cliente = clienteService.buscarPorId(idcliente);
            //email.
        if(service.emailJaExiste(email)) {
            attr.addFlashAttribute("fail", "Já existe este email.");                
        }else {
            emails.setEmail(email);
            emails.setNome(nome);
            emails.setCliente(cliente);
            emails.setEnvio_cobranca(envio_cobranca);
            service.salvar(emails);
            attr.addFlashAttribute("success", "E-mail inserido com sucesso.");              
        }   
        return "redirect:/emails/listar";
    }
```

And in the navigator console I can see:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/emails/salvar
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 405 
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

So the URL is correct.

Button code:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
                        <button id="add_email" type="button"
                            class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light"
                            th:id="${'addEmail_emails/salvar/' + cliente.id}"
                            onclick="salvarEmail();">Salvar</button>
```

Additionaly, the response header shows:

```
HTTP/1.1 405
Allow: GET
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 11 Mar 2021 21:28:40 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive
```

Can this be related to the fact that I use a modal (and the URL doesn't change when I open the modal, keeps a non-related with this email method URL "http://localhost:8080/clientes/cadastrar"), or the fact that I am using an onclick function instead of a form submit?

Comment: replace return "OK" with the redirect and see what happens. I think the Not supported part is related to the redirected URL.

Comment: Didn't get... I should replace  return "redirect:/emails/listar" for what? Also I added an information for response header in the post, seems like only get are allowed but I don't know why

Comment: Can you enter inside your salvar method? For some strange reason it seems like your server is telling you that for that specific URL, only the GET method is supported. See what you got from the response. "Allow: GET"

Comment: Yeah, I think I can't go inside the method. I don't know if this problem is related that the modal is opened in a page that have a different url(not .../emails) and some conflict is happening

Comment: My point is I think the error is related to the redirect string. I asked you to replace it to see if the error would change or not.
But actually, I don't understand why you do the redirect when you are calling the API through Ajax.

Comment: Can you show us the whole EmailController class? Or is that it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to CSRF token. because of Spring Security

Comment: It would be better if you also share the code to support the things you say along with the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try sending the csrf token and header along with your POST request.

```
function salvarEmail() {
        var token = $('#_csrf').attr('content');
        var header = $('#_csrf_header').attr('content');

        var cliente = /* [[cliente]] */ 0;
        var nome = Document.getElementById('nome').value;
        var email = Document.getElementById('email').value;
        var envio_cobranca = Document.getElementById('envio_cobranca').checked ? true : false;


        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
            },
            url : "/emails/salvar",
            type : 'POST',
            contentType : 'application/json',
            data : JSON.stringify({
                idcliente : 'cliente.idcliente',
                nome : nome,
                email : email,
                envio_cobranca : envio_cobranca
            }),
            success : function(data) {
                session = data.session;
            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It solved this specific error, but now I got the error "jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined".

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `@PostMapping("/salvar")` to `@PostMapping(path = "/salvar")`

Comment: Already tried this, but still getting the same error

Comment: "@RestController" is a convenience annotation for creating Restful controllers. It adds the "@Controller" and "@ResponseBody" annotations. It converts the response to JSON.

Comment: @Jordy yeah, you are right,  RestController doesn't help here, updated the answer

Comment: Have you tried to use RequestMapping annotation without methods instead of PostMapping?

Comment: @Connor have you tried use RequestBody and create POJO avoiding RequestParam